# How can I collect the amount of times a 3rd party dependency is used in my project and it's methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, abstract-syntax-tree

How do I go about collecting all the 3rd party libs that are used in my project and creating a list that will contain the name of the lib, and the number of times each of its methods has been called in a file e.g.

```
{
  lodash: {
    isArray: 5, // used 5 times in my project
    isEmpty: 3 
    etc...
  }
}
```

Would using an AST the only way to go about this or is there any simpler approaches?

Comment: AST is the only way bro

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with help of a tool I'm working on [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout)

```js
export const find = (ast, {traverse}) => {
    const result = {};
    
    traverse(ast, {
        '__a.__b()': (path) => {
            const {__a, __b} = getTemplateValues(path, '__a.__b()');
            const {name} = __a;
            const method = __b.name;

            result[name] = result[name] || {};
            result[name][method] = result[name][method] || 0;
            ++result[name][method]

        }
    });
    
    ast.program.body.push(ExpressionStatement(template.ast('(' + stringify(result) + ')')));
    
    return [];
};
```

Check it out in [Putout Editor](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/d89613cc4cbe5d099e4343f639ce87e0/72b58951ec49fae57b1d16f3e9a9de9c8267c827)

This is [Finder](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#finder), the most low level type of plugin.

What it does is search for all method calls, saves `result` object, and then
adds it to AST. Also it use [getTemplateValues](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/compare#gettemplatevaluesnode-template) to get nodes according to provided template.

So for data:

```js
lodash.isArray();
lodash.isEmpty();
lodash.isEmpty();
```

We will see result:

```js
lodash.isArray();
lodash.isEmpty();
lodash.isEmpty();

({
 'lodash': {
  'isArray': 1,
  'isEmpty': 2
 }
});
```